# Combinations with multiple groups

Tags: math, combinations, counting

How would you programmatically enumerate all possible unique combinations of a set of numbers into multiple groups?

For example, if I have the set {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} and I want 3 groups of size 3, 3, 2 one possible subset would be { [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8] }

this would be equivalent to { [3, 2, 1], [6, 5, 4], [7, 8] } and would be considered a duplicate

whereas { [4, 2, 3], [1, 5, 6], [7, 8] } would be considered a different subset

Obviously I am looking for the most efficient and practical way of doing this. I will be working with a fairly large N so the algorithm needs to be scalable.

Comment: Do you know how to iterate through all subsets of a given size?

Comment: There are a huge number of possible partitions you could come up with.  I doubt that anything will be scalable for large n.  What specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: It is not totally clear from your question if `{[4,5,6],[1,2,3],[7,8]}` would be considered equal to the two given examples as well. My answer below currently assumes no, but you might want to make that explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to think of this problem is as permutations of the multiset
`{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3}`. If such a permutation `p` has value `i` in position `j`, that would mean that the element `j` from your original set should be put in partition `i`.

Using e.g. the C++ template [`next_permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) you can enumerate these permutations as follows:

```cpp
int main() {
  int a[] = { 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2 };
  do {
    // Here a[j] == i means element j of your set goes in partition i.
    // Do whatever you want to do with the permutations generated this way.
  } while (std::next_permutation(a, a + 8));
}
```

The result will contain 10!/(3! 3! 2!) = 560 different combinations. A demo run of this code, including output similar to the notation used in your problem statement, is [available at ideone](http://ideone.com/ShSKEw). You can look at [the source code](http://repo.or.cz/w/official-gcc.git/blob/db3b35cb134d8947480488e1d4e412edb6e53f6b:/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h#l3622) if you want to know how `next_permutation` is implemented for gcc, but only do so if the license of your target project allows copying that code.